# sscanf error on scanning a formatted file

Tags: c, linux, string, unix, scanf

I am trying to read and parse an input file using `fgets()` and `sscanf()`. Here is my function (only the relevant part is listed here):

```
void reading_file(char* file)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(file, "r");
    char line[256];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f))
    {
        int i = 0;
        char str[20];
        sscanf(line, "%d %s", &i, str);
        printf("%d %s\n", i, str);
    }
}
```

The input file is:

```
0 be68c5bc1ee7be6f20728579ee082aed6214825b
1 e2d6c1bb794ff4545ef2f101ca904dbbb3ed3923
```

The output of this piece of code is:

```
875849270 aa71dbd21bd2b05f3bd261256f443fd5f9f7272e
1633890352 465c63da3d0168553c1027eb00ca364c337ced44
```

Totally wrong.

The funny part is here. If I use a struct to hold the input lines, the output is correct! Code after revising is here:

```
typedef struct s_s{
    int id;
    char hash[20];
} s_t;

void reading_file(char* file)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(file, "r");
    char line[256];
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f))
    {
        s_t s;
        sscanf(line, "%d %s", &s.id, s.hash);
        printf("%d %s\n", s.id, s.hash);
    }
}
```

The output is exact the same as the input file. Why is that? Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Why `char str[20];`, when you want to read lengthier strings.

Comment: It's pointless to try to make sense of behavior of code that leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: I am glad that your problem is solved. If you think any of the answers posted below has helped you in solving the problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the arrow next to the answer.  Once you accept an answer, answerer and you are awarded some reputation. With sufficient reputation you can vote up the answers that helped you. Also accepted answer float up to make it more useful for other readers.

Comment: @alvinzoo: Do not edit your question to indicate the answers solved it. Accept an answer solving it instead. (If neccessary, compose your own, if only reflecting comments marked Community Wiki, and accept that.)

Answer (score 0):

1. shouldn't `while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))` be `while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f))` ? 
   You can check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) of fgets().
2. Next, to correct the issue in your code, `char str[20];` needs to be changed to something like `char str[128];` because, the input from the file for the `string` is much longer than that of `20` charracters.

However, IMO, for the use of a structure returning the *correct* answer, is a part of [Undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).